# Why is the conditional subschema (JSON Schema Draft7) validation not working?

Tags: powershell, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Ref: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

**- Schema snippet**

```
"properties": {
    "country": {
      "default": "United States of America",
      "enum": [
        "United States of America",
        "Canada"
      ]
    },
    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "AddressLine1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "country": {
              "const": "United States of America"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "postal_code": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "else": {
          "postal_code": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "AddressLine1",
        "postal_code"
      ]
```

**Sample Data 1 - Expected Pass**

{
"address": {
"AddressLine1": "Address Line 1 in US",
"postal_code": 11779
}
}

**Sample Data 2  - Expected Fail**

{
"address": {
"AddressLine1": "Address Line 1 in Canada",
"postal_code": "RA90 188"
}
}

I expected the 2nd sample to fail but it passes without any issues.  I am using PowerShell Test-JSON for validation

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap `postal_code` in `"properties": { ... }` in your `then` and `else` clauses.

Comment: **Tried it as follows but no joy :( **                                                                                          
       "if": {
          "properties": {
            "#country": {
              "const": "United States of America"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {"postal_code": {
            "type": "integer"
          }}
        },
        "else": {
          "properties": {"postal_code": {
            "type": "string"
          }}

Comment: Would you be able to produce a minimal reproduceable example and share? Could use https://jsonschema.dev. This way, any ambiguities or inaccuraces in your schemas (such as the hash in "county" in your comment, and lack of "country" in your example data) won't be overlooked as a problem.

Comment: Here is the saved schema and working validation - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/hjyp2FLf  What I need is the code block "conditionalstuff": {"$ref": "#/definitions/domainenums" }     to support conditionality to switch between a strict enum or relaxed string types